# How to Get the CORRECT Pixel Colour

Tags: android, css

I would also like to read out the colour of the pixels from an 'Image'. I've read a lot of topics here about this but the success is still missing.
So after a lot of unwanted values, I tried to simplify my code and the Image as well. I tried with the following:

```css
//..
Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
Bitmap b = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Image, op);
//imageView.SetImageBitmap(b);
          
  int pixel1 = b.GetPixel(3, 4);
  int pixel2 = b.GetPixel(12, 11);
  int pixel3 = b.GetPixel(19, 20);
  int pixel4 = b.GetPixel(27, 28);
  int pixel5 = b.GetPixel(27, 19);
  int pixel6 = b.GetPixel(20, 11);
            
  int redV1 = Android.Graphics.Color.GetRedComponent(pixel1);
  int greenV1 = Android.Graphics.Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel1);
  int blueV1 = Android.Graphics.Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel1);

  int redV2 = Android.Graphics.Color.GetRedComponent(pixel2);
  int greenV2 = Android.Graphics.Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel2);
  int blueV2 = Android.Graphics.Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel2);
//..
```

Surprisingly I got the results as follows:
pixel1 color is OK. 
pixel2 color is NOT OK its pixel1 color.
pixel3 color is NOT OK its pixel2 color.
pixel4 color is NOT OK its pixel2 color.
pixel5 color is NOT OK its pixel2 color.
pixel6 color is NOT OK its existing color in my Image but on different coordinates. (it was not mentioned in my code)

Presentation of the .png Image in an imageView seems to be smooth.
Could anyone help with my fault?
THX!

pixel1..6 values seems to be correct (different on different colours and equal on the same) and they would be enough for me but all the values became -1 after I start to work with my real .png file (1500x1500 image as a resource). Is that too large to work with? What is the maximum in this case? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

... Ok, perhaps I got the fault. To be precise, not the fault but a usable solution! Now I'm trying with a smaller .png Image sized 500x500. It is small enough to work with. 
BUT: It seems the BitmapFactory creates a larger image (1000 x 1000). So I have to divide each coordinate with 2 if I want to check the correct colour on my original image. AND there is another problem: Some colours may be different read by the Getpixel(). It can be small differences in R,G,B values. In example: RGB(148,0,198) instead of (153,0,204). It means a 'bit' extra work for me to identify all the new 'Android colours' on my bitmap :( I hope, I could help for the others with this topic. It wasn't easy to find one bug/problem after another.